# Change Background Color When <li> is Active using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change background color of `<li>` where the class is active, when I click on those `li > a`. How can I do it in this case. He is what I have tried:

**Script**

```
<script>
    $('.sidebar-collapse .nav > li > a').click(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.removeAttr('background');
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Style**

```
.sidebar-collapse .nav > li > a {
    background: #EFEFEF;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #595959;
    border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
```

**Menu List HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="default.aspx"><i class="fa fa-desktop "></i>Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i>UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Notifications</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Elements</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Free Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-table "></i>Table Examples</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i>Forms </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap "></i>Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Second Level Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Second Level Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Second Level Link<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Third Level Link</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Third Level Link</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Third Level Link</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-qrcode "></i>Tabs & Panels</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>Mettis Charts</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i>Last Link </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="blank.aspx"><i class="fa fa-table "></i>Blank Page</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: you are looking for the `:active` pseudo selector

Comment: This is jquery not js.

Comment: i let to change code wait a minute

Comment: @Alek Like if jQuery is not javascript... :)

Comment: @user3001046 Why not pure CSS? `.sidebar-collapse .nav > li > a.active {background-color: transparent;} `

Comment: from JQuery-specs: $().removeAttr is working on elements attributes not on their style patterns, isn't it?

Comment: @epoch: _“you are looking for the `:active` pseudo selector”_ – most likely, the OP is _not_ looking for that; because `:active` per definition only applies to the short moment during which an element actually _gets_ “activated”, which is, quote from spec, _“[f]or example, between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it”_ – whereas usually what is wanted with this type of questions is to visibly highlight the “current” menu item for as long as the user stays on that page.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qaLkF) output?

Answer (score 1):

If you are somewhy bounded to js solution you need to use [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/). Since `background` is not an attribute but a style and can't be "removed".

```
$('.sidebar-collapse .nav > li > a').click(function (e) {
    var li = $(this).closest('li');
    if (li.hasClass('active')) {
        li.css('background-color', 'transparent'); //or inherit
    }
});
```

Or a pure CSS solution. Which is preferred:

```
.sidebar-collapse .nav > li.active > a {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: You will change like this .sidebar-collapse .nav > li.active > a {
    background-color: transparent;
}